# Run Java Applet

Tags: java, class, applet

I have downloaded a java applet class called AppletVerificacao.class from the web, and when I try to run it as an applet, Eclipse is unable to recognize it as an applet

When I right click the class and "Run as > Java Applet" I receive the following message:

[Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzXre.png)

Anybody has a clue ?

Comment: Applets no longer work.  Browsers have completely removed support for them & they've been deprecated and removed from the API.  It is best to transition away from applets to pure JS/HTML.